# How would I select distinct records from the same table on two different databases?

Tags: sql-server

I have two different databases that both contain a table with the same structure. I have to go across and select the distinct records across both, how is this best achieved? The uniqueness is based on `Id`. The other columns in the table could have varying data, but `Id` should be used as the basis of the distinct.

Structure is:

```
[Media_One].[dbo].[Video]
[Media_Two].[dbo].[Video]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, ...
FROM
(
  SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM Media_One.dbo.Video
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM Media_Two.dbo.Video
) AS x;
```

Answer (score 4):

This would suffice, since `UNION` **already** produces distinct results.

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM Media_One.dbo.Video
UNION
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM Media_Two.dbo.Video
```

Comment: Yes but note that the plan shape is quite different. UNION has a slightly higher estimated CPU cost and, in all of my tests, a slightly longer duration.